# How to align icons to the center of header text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got bolt and close icons with different sizes and would like to center them to the header text. I know I can achieve this by wrapping icons and header with div then apply `display: flex` and `align-items: center`. But problem is header is already wrapped with div and flex direction column is applied in order to align paragraph and button in column along with header. So how can I align icons to header text while header text is aligned to contents in the bottom with column? https://codepen.io/Judoboy/pen/eYPgqvP

```css
.bolt-icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.close-icon {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
}

.toast-details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.toast-container {
  max-width: 440px;
  display: flex;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="toast-container">

  <div class="bolt-icon">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 320 512" title="bolt">
    <path d="M296 160H180.6l42.6-129.8C227.2 15 215.7 0 200 0H56C44 0 33.8 8.9 32.2 20.8l-32 240C-1.7 275.2 9.5 288 24 288h118.7L96.6 482.5c-3.6 15.2 8 29.5 23.3 29.5 8.4 0 16.4-4.4 20.8-12l176-304c9.3-15.9-2.2-36-20.7-36z" />
  </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="toast-details">
    <h4> Header</h4>
    <p> Hello World!</p>
    <button>Click Me</button>
  </div>
  <div class="close-icon">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" title="window-close">
    <path d="M464 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h416c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm-83.6 290.5c4.8 4.8 4.8 12.6 0 17.4l-40.5 40.5c-4.8 4.8-12.6 4.8-17.4 0L256 313.3l-66.5 67.1c-4.8 4.8-12.6 4.8-17.4 0l-40.5-40.5c-4.8-4.8-4.8-12.6 0-17.4l67.1-66.5-67.1-66.5c-4.8-4.8-4.8-12.6 0-17.4l40.5-40.5c4.8-4.8 12.6-4.8 17.4 0l66.5 67.1 66.5-67.1c4.8-4.8 12.6-4.8 17.4 0l40.5 40.5c4.8 4.8 4.8 12.6 0 17.4L313.3 256l67.1 66.5z" />
  </svg>
  </div>

</div>
```